# How can i get all the Mesh Colliders Components i added to all models and objects in Hierarchy?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

To add them all i marked and selected in the Hierarchy all the models and objects and then in the meny i did Component > Physics > Mesh Collider

But now i want to delete/remove all the Mesh Colliders i added.
But i want to do it with a script.

What i want is to list in array or List all the Mesh Colliders and then to decide what to do with each one of them if to delete rename or anything else.

```
GameObject.FindObjectsOfType(typeof(MonoBehaviour)); //returns Object[]
GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Untagged");  //returns GameObject[]
```

This will return all the gameobjects but it's not what i need.

Answer (score 1):

With `FindObjectsOfType`:

To find with MeshColliders with `FindObjectsOfType`, provide `MeshCollider` as the type. Convert it into `MeshCollider` array.

```
    MeshCollider[] allMeshes = GameObject.FindObjectsOfType(typeof(MeshCollider)) as MeshCollider[];
    for (int i = 0; i < allMeshes.Length; i++)
    {
        allMeshes[i].enabled = false; //Optional
        Destroy(allMeshes[i]);
    }
```

With `FindGameObjectsWithTag`:

Find the GameObject that contains the Colliders with their tags. Store to GameObject array then use `getComponent` to get the `MeshCollider` from them.

```
    GameObject[] tempObj = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Untagged") as GameObject[];
    MeshCollider[] allMeshes = new MeshCollider[tempObj.Length];


    for (int i = 0; i < allMeshes.Length; i++)
    {
        allMeshes[i] = tempObj[i].GetComponent<MeshCollider>();
        if (allMeshes[i] != null)
        {
            allMeshes[i].enabled = false; //Optional
            Destroy(allMeshes[i]);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? If so, you can accept it as answer. Thanks.